# MongoDb $group, count on the wrong field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have written this query that works almost perfectly, but the count is not made on the right attribute or field.

Here is the query :

```
db.getCollection("applications").aggregate([
    {$match: {
        "history.1": {"$exists": true}
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: "$_id",
        dateDeb: { // beginning date
            $arrayElemAt: [("$history.createdOn"), 0]
        },
        dateFin: { // end date
            $arrayElemAt: [("$history.createdOn"), 1]
        }
    }},
    {$project: {
        dateDiff: {
            $divide: [
                {$subtract: ["$dateFin", "$dateDeb"]},
                (1000 * 3600 * 24)
            ]
        }
    }},
    {$project: {
        diffArrondi: {$trunc: "$dateDiff"} // rounded diff
    }},
    {$project: {
        diffFinal: {
            $cond: [
                {$lte: ["$diffArrondi", 1]},
                -1, 
                "$diffArrondi"
            ]
        }
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        nbrJour: {$addToSet: "$diffFinal"}, // days count
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }},
    {$unwind: {path: "$nbrJour"}},
    {$sort: {"nbrJour": 1}}
])
```

Actually the count reflects the number of documents that have at least an array history of 2. But I would like the count to be on the final field: `nbrJour` (days count).

View the actual result. Where do I go wrong.

[image: The actual result]

Comment: Can you add some sample documents from your collection with expected json output ?

Comment: The output is already there, what I want as result  is the time that a history stayed in a particuklar status. Want to know how many lasted -1 day, 1 days...n days. Hence my group by. Will post the model as weel.

Answer (score 0):

export interface IApplication {
    id: string,

```
status: IStatus,

organization: IOrganization,

audit: IAudit,

history: IHistory[],

watchers?: IWatchers,

sections: {
    applicant?: {
        organizationName?: string,
        name?: string,
        phone?: string,
        phoneExtension?: string,
        mobile?: string,
        address?: string,
        email?: string,
    },
    project?: {
        urgent?: boolean,
        name?: string,
        number?: string,
        location?: string,
        drawing?: string,
        description?: string,
        attachedSketchPlanNumber?: string,
        specialRequirements?: string,
        municipality?: string,
        workType?: string,
        CSEMRequired?: boolean,
        CSEMApplicationNumber?: string
    },
    work?: {
        startDate?: string,
        endDate?: string,
        obstructingTraffic?: boolean,
        obstructionDescription?: string,
        excavation?: boolean,
        surfaceArea?: string,
        paving?: string,
        pavement?: string,
        other?: string,
        signature?: string,
        signatureDate?: string,
    },
    publicRightsManager?: {
        name?: string,
        phone?: string,
        phoneExtension?: string,
        mobile?: string,
        address?: string,
        email?: string
    },
    internalConsultations?: IInternalConsultation[],
    consent?: {
        trafficPlan?: boolean,
        expiresOn?: string,
        specialRequirements?: string,
        CSEMApproved?: boolean,
        CSEMApprovedOn?: string,
        CSEMApprovedBy?: string,
        CSEMApprovalAttached?: boolean,
        estimatedCostOfDegradation?: number,
        fee?: number,
        granted?: boolean,
        revise?: boolean,
        signature?: string,
        signatureDate?: string,
        startDate?: string,
        endDate?: string,
        distanceArterial?: string,
        pavementAgeArterial?: string,
        typeLastInterventionArterial?: string,
        distanceLocal?: string,
        pavementAgeLocal?: string,
        typeLastInterventionLocal?: string
    },
    documents?: IAttachedDocument[],
    comments?: IComment[],
}
```

}

interface ApplicationDocument extends IApplication, mongoose.Document {
}

Answer (score 0):

"export class ApplicationDAO extends DAOImpl {
    constructor() {
        const auditUser = {
            id: String,
            name: String,
        }

```
    const audit = {
        createdBy: auditUser,
        createdOn: Date,
        lastModifiedBy: auditUser,
        lastModifiedOn: Date,
    };

    const auditableEntry = {
        id: String,
        createdBy: auditUser,
        createdOn: Date,
        disabled: Boolean,
    };

    const internalConsultation = Object.assign(auditableEntry, {
        service: String,
        documentsAttached: Boolean,
    });

    const comment = Object.assign(auditableEntry, {
        comment: String,
        included: Boolean,
    });

    const attachedDocument = Object.assign(auditableEntry, {
        name: String,
        link: String,
    });


    const history = {
        // id: String,
        createdBy: auditUser,
        createdOn: Date,
        summary: {
            content: Boolean,
            comments: Boolean,
            documents: Boolean,
            status: {
                from: String,
                to: String,
            }
        }
    };

    const watchers = {
        applicants: String,
        reviewers: String
    }"
```